# Map language in Google Maps API v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, internationalization

How do you change the language of the objects on an embedded map (streets, cities...) using Google Maps v3? I'm in Finland and need the data in Swedish which is available on the normal Google Maps site.

Setting the &language=sv parameter only seems to affect the user interface, not the actual map.

Comment: This is the way to go. But not everything is translated. It depends on the language. You can test it here: http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/map_language/map_lang.html As you can see, driving directions are translated in your language. As an example: Turn it into English and Moskva becomes Moscow. Turn it into French and it will still display Moskva instead of Moscou.

Comment: It's strange though, addresses seem to be translated but not the actual map canvas. When browsing to the maps site everything is translated, but through the API it shows everything in the majority language (Finnish).